# Finding a gap between timestamps (for multiple entries)

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, gaps-and-islands

I have a table with a list of vehicles and timestamps of adding and deleting them from the database. A single vehicle can be added by more than one user, so there can be more than one row when a specific license plate is 'active' on some point (added to the database but not deleted). Periods can overlap.

| license_plate | create_timestamp | delete_timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AA-BBB-CC | 2019-10-26 0:04:57 | 2021-04-07 14:18:44 |
| AA-BBB-CC | 2021-04-07 16:00:43 | \N |

How to check if there was a gap for a specific license plate in the entire period I'am checking?
There are multiple rows with start_date and and date (or with no end date if it wasn't deleted), I need to find out if there is any gap between first start_date and last end_date for a specific car.
I need to group vehicles into 3 groups: Active (never completely deleted from the database), Deleted and Resurrected (deleted but re-entered - for this group I need to determine the gap).
I tried to create tables with one row per a car based on a row number

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY license_plate ORDER BY create_timestamp, delete_timestamp) AS rank
```

and after having multiple tables compare entries row by row:

```
CASE WHEN r1.delete_timestamp is null THEN 'Active'
     WHEN r1.delete_timestamp < r2.create_timestamp AND r2.delete_timestamp is null THEN 'Active'
     WHEN r1.delete_timestamp > r2.create_timestamp AND r2.delete_timestamp is null THEN 'Resurrected'
     WHEN r1.delete_timestamp > r2.create_timestamp AND r2.delete_timestamp is not null 
          AND r3.create_timestamp is null THEN 'Deleted'
     end so on for next rows :)
     END AS Vehicle_status
```

But it doesn't make sense as there are currently vehicles with 20 rows (entries) and can be more in the future.

Hope someone has any idea how to solve it :)

Comment: You can compare a calendar table of a ganuality needed to the license plates intervals and find the timestamps of inactivity.

Comment: What is your DBMS?

Comment: Hi Serg, I am working in Presto.

I've found here a nice solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21257869/check-date-split-periods-are-continuous?answertab=createdasc#tab-top

Currently I am struggling with implementing it ot my query. But this is what I am looking for!