# Check date split periods are continuous (and spotting the gaps)

Tags: sql, presto, gaps-and-islands

I am struggling with a similar issue like in this thread:
[Check date split periods are continuous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21257869/check-date-split-periods-are-continuous?answertab=createdasc#tab-top)

Can someone help me translate the Qsebas' answer to Presto language? As this is exactly what I'd like to achieve.

I am not sure what supposed to be the outcome of this part:

```
CROSS APPLY  Enumerate ( ABS(DATEDIFF(d, From_Date, To_Date))) AS NUMBERS
```

And how to replace it. Would it be ROW_NUMBER () as a one column and ABS(DATE_DIFF()) in the second?

My sample data:

| license_plate | create_timestamp | delete_timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AA-AAA | 2019-10-08 10:47:54 | \N |
| AA-AAA | 2021-01-22 12:37:21 | 2021-07-21 8:27:44 |
| AA-AAA | 2021-07-19 9:10:39 | \N |
| BB-BBB | 2016-04-15 8:38:59 | 2021-11-04 10:51:18 |
| BB-BBB | 2018-03-13 13:56:39 | 2021-10-07 08:21:07 |
| BB-BBB | 2021-12-23 12:42:31 | \N |
| CC-CCC | 2019-07-26 21:22:42 | 2021-12-17 18:21:37 |
| CC-CCC | 2021-11-05 11:08:13 | 2022-02-11 08:44:22 |

I would like to get sth like that:

| license_plate | create_timestamp | delete_timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AA-AAA | 2019-10-08 10:47:54 | \N |
| BB-BBB | 2016-04-15 8:38:59 | 2021-10-07 08:21:07 |
| BB-BBB | 2021-12-23 12:42:31 | \N |
| CC-CCC | 2019-07-26 21:22:42 | 2022-02-11 08:44:22 |

There can be also a column count_ranges to count how many ranges for each license plate there were.
There can be many entries for every license plate and they can overlap (so sorting by the create_timestamp and comparing row by row doesn't work).
The idea is to group vehicles (license plates) into:

- 'Active' (there was no gap since first create_timestamp till now/end_date); license_plate AA-AAA in my example
- 'Reactivated' (there was at least on gap but the car is active now) - license_plate BB-BBB
- 'Deleted' (there was no gap since first create_timestamp and last delete_timestamp but it is not active now) - license_plate CC-CCC

I know there could be more scenarios (i.e. 'Reactivated - Deleted', 'Reactivated - Reactivated' but this split will do for now.

If I had a table that I'd like I could then assign them to groups by:

```
CASE WHEN count_ranges > 1 THEN 'Reactivated'
           WHEN count_ranges = 1 AND delete_timestamp is null THEN 'Active'
           WHEN count_ranges = 1 AND delete_timestamp is not null THEN 'Deleted'
END AS vehicle_status
```

Maybe there is a different way to achieve this?

PS. Listing the exact delete_timestamp at the end of the range and create_timestamp at the beginning of the next range for a single license plate would be useful to check if a license plate was reactivated by the same user or by someone else.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar with presto, but it'd probably help if you posted an example of the raw data - and expected results.

Comment: Hi @SOS , I have edited and updated my post with more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Guru Stron, you directed me to the right solution!

I upgraded your code by adding one column to my initial database:

```
select v.*,
       max(delete_timestamp) over (partition by license_plate 
       order by create_timestamp, delete_timestamp ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) 
       as moving_max

from vehicles v
```

End then I compare next create_timestamp with previous moving_max instead of previous delete_timestamp

Didn't check with your part of code yet. But if it worked before (not as I'd like but as you intended ;) ) and my updated database looks good with the new column (every license plate has its moving_max calculated correctly) so it can't work wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Using sample data from the linked answer I suggest to use gaps and islands approach - use `lag` to compare previous `to_date` with current `from_date` and then use the result for rolling sum to form the grouping:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset (ref, from_date, to_date) AS (
    VALUES ('A', date '1997-01-04', date '1998-01-04'),
        ('A', date '1998-01-04', date '1998-05-27'),
        ('A', date '1998-05-27', date '1999-01-04'),
        ('B', date '1997-01-04', date '1998-01-04'),
        ('B', date '1998-01-04', date '1998-07-26'),
        ('B', date '2012-01-04', date '2013-01-04')
)

-- query
select ref,
    min(from_date) from_date,
    max(to_date) to_date,
    max(grp) over(partition by ref) + 1 count_ranges
from(
        select ref,
            from_date,
            to_date,
            sum(if(grp > 0, 1, 0)) over(partition by ref order by from_date, to_date) as grp
        from (
                select *,
                    coalesce(
                        date_diff('day', lag(to_date) over(partition by ref order by from_date, to_date), from_date),
                        0
                    ) as grp
                from dataset
            )
    )
group by ref, grp
```

Output:

| ref | from_date | to_date | count_ranges |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1997-01-04 | 1999-01-04 | 1 |
| B | 1997-01-04 | 1998-07-26 | 2 |
| B | 2012-01-04 | 2013-01-04 | 2 |

Comment: That's great but I can see on issue here (but I might be wrong of course). Does it compare row by row and 'forget' previous timestamps? Because they can overlap.

create_timestamp1:  2019-10-08 10:47:54 
delete_timestamp1:  \N 
create_timestamp2: 2021-01-22 12:37:21 
delete_timestamp2: 2021-07-11 8:27:44 
create_timestamp3: 2021-07-19 9:10:39 
delete_timestamp3: \N 

So there is a gap between delete2 and create3 but record 1 was never deleted.
The vehicle should be counted as 'Active' but it will be as 'Resurrected'

Comment: For calculations I would also add  Coalesce(delete_timestamp,now()) to get rid of '\N' records.   And the query should somehow 'remember' the highest previous timestamp when comparing to the next row.

Comment: @KamilDworzecki I've used the data sample from the linked question and have not seen the update to yours. If this does not work for you I will try to dive deeper tomorrow if I'll have time.

Comment: How about adding a column moving_max to the main data base?
 Is it possible to create sth like: Select Max(delete_timestamp) Over (Partition by license_plate order by create_timestamp) as moving_max FROM vehicles WHERE create_timestamp <= lead(create_timestamp) over(partition by license_plate order by create_timestamp, delete_timestamp) as moving_max

Your query will work if I had a column like this 

I hope you understand. Sorry I am chaotic, just thinking loud before going sleep ;)

Comment: @KamilDworzecki yes, using `max` over partitioned and ordered can do the trick.